# Why do Angular built-in directives not work on a single component?

Tags: angular

I'm using

- angular ^9.1.11
- node 12.18.0.

My issue:

Built-in directives like `ngIf` or `ngFor` are not working, and I know that I have to import `CommonModule`.

My scenario:
I have module, with a router component and three sub components. All components are imported into the module. All components work as expected (`*ngIf`, `*ngFor`, ...) except for one (also no errors).

My component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-component',
  templateUrl: './my-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-component.component.scss'],
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  list = [1,2,4]
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```

My template:

```
<div class="container">
  {{list.length}} // 3
  <div *ngFor="let item of list">TEST</div> // not looping
  <div *ngIf="true">TEST</div> // not showing
</div>
```

I can create a new component which would work like expected and cherrypick my changes into the new component but I would like to know how this could happen. The component did work before and I'm afraid that it might break again in the future even if I create a new one.

Comment: Could you create and include an [mcve]? Also can you include the entire template that is causing problems, not just the fragment?

Comment: Apart from one extra `div`(need to remove it) everything else is fine and would work also.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit late. But i managed to solve this issue myself.

The issue was that this component was not part of a module which importet the CommonModule which is needed for some features that someone might take for given.

Hope this will help anyone who will encounter the same issue.

Answer (score -2):

Angular doesn't support more than one structural directive on the same element. As a workaround use the

```
<ng-container *ngIf="show">
  <div *ngFor="let thing of stuff">
    {{log(thing)}}
    <span>{{thing.name}}</span>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: The code posted in the question only shows 1 structure directive per element...